# catching elements when displaying others using css

Tags: css, wordpress

I have this class for my menu: `.site-header-menu`

and I have this class for my content: `.content`

what should I do to catch `.content` when `.site-header-menu` is displayed?

I already tried this but it doesn't work:

```
.site-header-menu + .content{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Do you have some suggestion? This kind of things are possible using css?

I'm using Wordpress so this is my php struture in header.php. The idea is to hide the content of my page template when `site-header-menu` is open:

```
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) || has_nav_menu( 'social' ) ) : ?>
                    <!--<button id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentysixteen' ); ?></button>-->
                    <button id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle" data-title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></button>


                    <div id="site-header-menu" class="site-header-menu">
                        <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>
                            <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Primary Menu', 'twentysixteen' ); ?>" data-title= ''>

                                <?php
                                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                                        'theme_location' => 'primary',
                                        'menu_class'     => 'primary-menu',
                                     ) );
                                ?>

                            </nav><!-- .main-navigation -->
                        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML ?

Comment: can you post a bit of your html structure?

Comment: ok, but where is your .content?

Comment: hello I already paste some of my php. My content is in a page.php I'm using wordpress @Vixed

Answer (score 0):

How is `.site-header-menu` being displayed? Is a class being added to display the menu or is its display property being directly manipulated by JavaScript? There is no indication how you can tell if the menu is displayed?

> .site-header-menu + .content{
>     opacity: 0;
>   }

The above rule, because of the plus sign, will only apply if the element with class `content` is immediately following the element with class `site-header-menu` in the DOM. For example:

```
<div class="site-header-menu">
     ... menu stuff ...
</div>

<div class="content">
     ... content stuff ...
</div>
```

This might be the problem, but without actually seeing the output HTML it's hard to say.

If you are using PHP or JS to toggle the visibility of the menu you could potentially add/remove an additional class to `.content` that will hide/show it based on the menu being displayed or not.

```
/* CSS rule to hide the .content element */
.content.hideMe {
     visibility: none;
}

// pseudo-script click event handler (NOT REAL SCRIPT!)
function menuButtonClick() {
     if (menuCurrentlyDisplayed) {
          // menu is already displayed so hide it and show content
          hideMenu;
          removeClass(".content", "hideMe");
     } else {
          // menu is not yet displayed so show it and hide content
          showMenu;
          addClass(".content", "hideMe");
     }
}
```

If you could post your output HTML, or set up a fiddle for us to take a look, it would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Dave I will learn how to set up a fiddle and I will put it here.